# BEM solver derivatives

Tags: derivative, openmdao

During the OpenMDAO workshop in 2022 it has been mentioned that someone did some work on the analytic (or algorithmic?) derivatives for a Boundary Element Method solver, for the use in gradient-based optimisations, and would be willing to share. Is there any reference to that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the workshop presentations and contact information will be posted on the OpenMDAO website by mid November 2022. Keep an eye out [here](https://openmdao.org/news/) for when that is posted.

Answer (score 0):

All workshop proceeding presentations have been posted:
https://openmdao.org/2022-workshop-proceedings/

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are talking about my presentation. I DID NOT derive/calculate the adjoint for that project but just used finite difference for the project. However, I would more than welcome any opportunity to discuss this topic.